# When using cmake FetchContent, how to use the one locally when available?

Tags: c++, cmake

Some of the package is really huge, while the `apt` downloaded version is much smaller. I wish I can use the apt installed version when available. At the same tile still left the option to download during calling cmake for other users.

For example I have apt installed some package as pkg-dev.

After I use the combination of

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  pkg
  GIT_REPOSITORY sth
  GIT_TAG        sth
  FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(pkg)
```

It will download the package from git no matter whether I have it installed offline. To expand this question, if I can use bash command `locate` to find the packag in `/usr/lib` `/usr/include`. Sould I put them in FetchContent as well?

Comment: Your snippet should work and calls `find_package` first. It probably fails to find the library. Call it manually to get an idea why that is the case.

Comment: Can you try running `cmake` with `--debug-find` to find out where it tries to locate the package? And can you please add the name of the package you installed from apt and which OS version you're using? I suspect that the apt package might not include the cmake config files necessary to work with `find_package`, as I've unfortunately seen that quite often. But I can't check without knowing which package it is. Please also include the actual `FetchContent` calls you're making, there might be a mismatch in the package name and the name you're using for FetchContent.